# parse assembly strings in vhdl from an external .txt file

Tags: vhdl

I am writing a 32-bit mips processor with VHDL and I am trying to write a text file that contains the instructions in string forms like "lw $s1, 100($s2)" and then convert it to machine code.

Is it possible to write a converter code in VHDL to convert the string to machine code? As we can only read one "binary"? character at a time, is it possible to parse the above string in a VHDL code?

Comment: It's possible but a lot of work. You should use a scripting language like Python to convert it into a better format directly readable from VHDL. E.g. a file with an array of record elements describing your commands.

Comment: What a strange idea. Why don't you use an assembler to do the job?

Comment: If you really want to write a parser I VHDL you can get inspiration from those that already done that. Here's a TCL interpreter http://kevinpt.github.io/vertcl/

Comment: The google code link in the above vertcl link is dead. Kevin's TCL interpreter in VHDL  vertcl can be found at https://github.com/kevinpt/vertcl and the associated vhdl-extras can be found at https://github.com/kevinpt/vhdl-extras .

Comment: Note vertcl is not synthesis eligible,which would require doing away with access types (pointers) and require memory management. The complexity would be on the order of a design for a processor.